# How to clear all the elements of array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
volatile static uint8_t buffer[16];
void ResetBuffer(){     
   for(int i=strlen((char*)buffer);i>=0;i--) buffer[i]='\0'; 
}
```

The buffer variable must be always used in micro controller, so I've used volatile static and it's global variable.
**But, to make all the buffer clear, is it right to code like this? If it's wrong or there's any other simple code, please show me some simple code.**

I've heard that if I want to make it clear, then it would be easier to just make the first element empty. like this : buffer[0] = '\0';
But, when I code it like that, another elements are still remained.

I know it's a very simple question.
But I'm confused. I've been normally programming in C++ or Java, so it's quite confused for me to program in C.

Comment: strlen may cause a crash if your buffer is not null terminated.

Comment: I've missed it, Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your use of `strlen()` is wrong, that is reliant on the contents of the buffer being a valid string; it doesn't clear the entire buffer.

Just use `memset()` with `sizeof`:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
```

Note that `sizeof` is not a function, so no parentheses are needed (or should be used, in my opinion) for cases like these.

If your C library doesn't include `memset()`, a plain loop can of course be used:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buffer; ++i)
  buffer[i] = 0;
```

If you want to clear just the part that is used, and know that it's a valid string, your code works of course. I probably wouldn't have used backwards looping since I find that unintuitive but that's just me.

Note: if this buffer is for strings, it should be changed to have type `char`, not `uint8_t`.

Comment: finally someone realizes that `sizeof` is not a function… +1!

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I've been aware for quite a while, but still it's fun to be appreciated of course. Thanks.

Comment: too many myths and wrong assumptions in our field! I regularly link to your "don't cast the return value of malloc" answer as well…

Comment: @unwind Thank you, but, actually I don't need to clear entire buffer, I think i've posted wrong. I just want to make the letters(string) that was used before, to become erased in the buffer. In this case, is it fine?

Comment: Yes, clear the whole thing. Setting each element to `0` does that and the few additional clock-ticks required to clear it all is easily less than required for the arithmetic to clear only a limited few.

Comment: @unwind:I think passing `uint8_t*` to `strlen` even with cast is constraint violation (not sure but I think so).

Comment: @Giorgi Good point, I edited to mention type-change recommendation.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I got something new knowledge from you thank you so much.

Comment: @unwind:so if user wants to stick with `uint8_t*` then safest way to pass that to `strlen` is to first do a `memcpy` of that array to a `char` array, and then pass that `char` array to strlen?

Comment: @Giorgi No, that would be very weird and scary. Probably better to re-implement `strlen()` for `uint8_t` arrays, but if the user is storing 0-terminated text then the buffer really should be `char`.

Comment: @unwind:scary but it should work if in this uint8_t* array only ASCII text is stored I guess? I understand your other recommendation. But sometimes I have come accross situations when you mix text and binary data in one buffer, and then for convenience I have used unsigned char array for both

Comment: @Giorgi Really, just clear the entire buffer always, and never use `strlen()`, then the problem goes away.

Comment: @unwind:why would it be scary?

Comment: @Giorgi Because it would be so very clearly wasteful, it would make me doubt the sanity of whoever wrote it. It's so far from the simplest, most straight-forward solution to a very simple problem, that it is scary.

Comment: @unwind: Yes but imagine the setting is that you *have* a string in a `uint8_t *` buffer. You don't suggest to reimplement all string functions for uint8_t type right? (like you suggested with strlen). So that, what remains?

Comment: Just clear the entire buffer with a single `memset()`, and be done.

Comment: @unwind:I can see you are not following me. Ok, otherwise it is getting long discussion. See my comment once again above- I am not asking related to this SO question, my question was more general.

Comment: Please clarify that you don't need parentheses because `buffer` is an expression and not a type.

Comment: sizeof, like typeof, alignof, and attribute, is not a function but behaves like a function, so using parentheses increases readability in the general case. Try sizeof without parentheses with more complex expressions. Of course, it's a matter of bad style or good style.

Answer (score 6):

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: @FrerichRaabe except that `sizeof(buffer)` is already the size, in bytes, of the buffer. It is **wrong** to multiply by `sizeof(*buffer)`.

Answer (score 5):

Assigning '\0' to the first element to the character array is enough to make it an empty string but it does not clear the entire array.

In order to clear you need to use

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

or

```
bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: Note that `bzero` is not standard. From `bzero` manual: `4.3BSD.   This  function   is   deprecated   (marked   as   LEGACY   in POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new programs.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of bzero().`

Comment: @sreeyesh But, why not code like this : memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer)); cause I've known that it's different between '\0' and 0.

Comment: @Sean Charecter '\0' has ascii value 0. So it does't matter whether you use 0 or '\0', the compiler will always pass the value 0 in both cases. But the second argument of memset is an integer. Since '\0' is a charecter constant, a type casting will be done by the compiler. However its handled by the compiler.